# Reflected XSS on BufferedReader readLine() method

Tags: java, xss, bufferedreader, encoder, checkmarx

I have scanned a java web project with the Checkmarx tool, and the analysis marks an XSS vulnerability in a method where a web service is executed that responds a JSON, the vulnerability is in the line `while((output = Encode.forJava(br.readLine())) != null) {`, specifically in `br.readLine()`.

Checkmarx says:

> The attacker would be able to alter the returned web page by simply
> providing modified data in the user input `readLine`, which is read by
> the `NetClientPost` method. This input then flows through the code
> straight to the output web page, without sanitization.
> This can enable a Reflected Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) attack.

I tried with OWASP for Java, implementing the method `Encode.forJava()`, but the vulnerability continues to appear in the analysis. This is the implementation of the method:

```
public String NetClientPost (String urlSer, String param){
        String result ="";
        try {
            InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            String host = ip.getHostAddress();
            doTrustToCertificates();
            URL url = new URL(urlSer);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            conn.setConnectTimeout(2000);
            String input = param;
            String output = "";

            try(OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream()) {
                os.write(input.getBytes());
                os.flush();
                if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP  code : " + conn.getResponseCode());
                }
                
                try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())))) {
                    while ((output = Encode.forJava(br.readLine())) != null) {//LINE OF CHECKMARX XSS
                        result += output;
                    }
                }
            }
            
            conn.disconnect();
            return result;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            return result;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Any have an idea of how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try parsing the incoming data as JSON and then serializing it back to a string before sending it on.

That way you can be sure that your method only returns JSON to the client.  If for some reason, your incoming data isn't JSON, then your method would encounter an error parsing the JSON, which you can then handle appropriately.

`Encode.forJava` isn't a helpful method to use here: it is used to encode a string to be inserted into a Java string literal.

Comment: This works for me. My Checkmarx tool error all gone after making this fix.

I just converted the String to Json (Using ObjectMapper) and again convert to String.

Answer (score 0):

output = Encode.forHtmlAttribute(br.readLine() works for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).